# Gridview - Update event not fire

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row, edit

When I click the "Edit" button of the gridview, it will show "Update" and "Cancel" button. But when I click "Update" button, it will not fire any event "RowUpdating", RowUpdated", "RowCommand"... It reload the page and then gridview disappear.

The following is my asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
AutoGenerateColumns = "False" Font-Names = "Arial"
Font-Size = "10pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="false" 
AllowPaging ="True"  
PageSize = "20"
OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">       
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
<Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "Name&Post" HeaderText = "Name & Post"  ReadOnly ="true" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Working<br>Time">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lb1_rosterkey"  runat="server"  Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_RosterKey")%>'  Visible ="false" ></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1_shifttype" runat ="server"  Enabled ="false"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField ="en_name" DataValueField ="shift_type_key">       </asp:DropDownList>
<MKB:TimeSelector ID="Col1_StartTime" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False" ReadOnly="true" MinuteIncrement="1" AmPm="AM" BorderColor="Silver" 
                            Date="" Hour="07" Minute="0"  SelectedTimeFormat="Twelve">   </MKB:TimeSelector>
<MKB:TimeSelector ID="Col1_EndTime" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False"  ReadOnly="true" MinuteIncrement="1" AmPm="PM" BorderColor="Silver" 
                            Date="" Hour="07" Minute="0" SelectedTimeFormat="Twelve">   </MKB:TimeSelector>                                 
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1_shifttype" runat ="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField ="en_name" DataValueField ="shift_type_key"></asp:DropDownList>
<MKB:TimeSelector ID="Col1_StartTime" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False"  MinuteIncrement="1" AmPm="AM" BorderColor="Silver" 
                            Date="" Hour="07" Minute="0"  SelectedTimeFormat="Twelve">     </MKB:TimeSelector>
<MKB:TimeSelector ID="Col1_EndTime" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False"  MinuteIncrement="1" AmPm="PM" BorderColor="Silver" 
                            Date="" Hour="07" Minute="0" SelectedTimeFormat="Twelve">    </MKB:TimeSelector>
</EditItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Leave/<br>TOIL">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_VL" Enabled="false" Text="VL" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_VL")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_SL" Enabled="false" Text="SL" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_SL")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_ML" Enabled="false" Text="ML" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_ML")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_PH" Enabled="false" Text="PH" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_PH")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_APH" Enabled="false" Text="APH" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_APH")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_TOIL" Enabled="false" Text="TOIL" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_TOIL")%> />
<br />
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_Others")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_VL" Text="VL" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_VL")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_SL"  Text="SL" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_SL")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_ML"  Text="ML" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_ML")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_PH"  Text="PH" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_PH")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_APH"  Text="APH" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_APH")%> />
<asp:CheckBox
ID="cb1_TOIL" Text="TOIL" 
runat="server"
Checked=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_TOIL")%> />
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1_Others" runat="server" Width="50" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1_Others") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

......

The following is the VB code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    'Set the edit index.
    Gridview1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex        
    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    'Reset the edit index.
    Gridview1.EditIndex = -1
    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    'Retrieve the table from the session object.
    Dim dt = CType(Session("dt"), DataTable)

    'Update the values.
    Dim row = Gridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex)



    'Reset the edit index.
    Gridview1.EditIndex = -1

    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
End Sub

Private Sub BindData()

    Dim StartDateStr As String

    StartDateStr = Trim(Request.QueryString("sd"))
    StartDateStr = Left(StartDateStr, 10)
    'date should be best in ISO format, i.e. yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss[.mmm] as "Set Dateformat dmy" is not supported by DataSet object
    'StartDateStr = Right(StartDateStr, 4) & "-" & Mid(StartDateStr, 4, 2) & "-" & Left(StartDateStr, 2) & " T00:00:00"

    Dim StartDate As DateTime
    Dim EndDate As DateTime
    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateStr)
    EndDate = Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 6, StartDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")

    g_header1 = StartDate   'Monday
    g_header2 = Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, StartDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    g_header3 = Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2, StartDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    g_header4 = Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 3, StartDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    g_header5 = Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 4, StartDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    g_header6 = Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 5, StartDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    g_header7 = EndDate     'Sunday

    Gridview1.DataSource = Session("dt")
    Gridview1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
        'If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
        Dim Col1_StartTime = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Col1_StartTime"), MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector)
        'set the TimePicker's Value here according to the Time-Value in the DataRow'
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Gridview1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Update" Then
        'Reset the edit index.
        Gridview1.EditIndex = -1

        'Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: where is your edit button markup? `AutoGenerateEditButton="false" `?

Comment: Sorry, i missing the markup in the code:   <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
<ItemStyle Width="80px" /></asp:CommandField>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I need to set CausesValidation="false"

Answer (score 2):

Use buttons in asp:TemplateField with proper `CommandName` and it will fire the corresponding events.

Example

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="btnEdit" runat="server" commandname="Edit" text="Edit" />
            <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" commandname="Delete" text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="btnUpdate" runat="server" commandname="Update" text="Update" />
            <asp:Button id="btnCancel" runat="server" commandname="Cancel" text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

make `enableviewstate=true` in gridview

Answer (score 0):

did you write this at page load, if not add this

```
if me.ispostback= false then
'grid fill statement

end if
```

Comment: Yes, I had add this to page_load, but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your save/cancel buttons are located but you may need to add a command name to them as specified on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

ie.  `<asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" commandname="Update" text="Update"/>`

Comment: hi, because i use the following code: <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
<ItemStyle Width="80px" /></asp:CommandField>

Answer (score 0):

I never used separate rowupdate/rowedit commands but i do use the following:

in my grid columns list, i'm adding the commandfield and images (optional for the buttons)

```
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="Image" ShowCancelButton="true" ShowEditButton="True"
            EditImageUrl="../images/esig.gif" CancelImageUrl="../images/btn_close.gif"
            UpdateImageUrl="../images/icn_ok.gif" />
```

I don't see this in your code.

a sample of a grid-editing as below
[image]

In the code behind, you should be able to check for the RowDataBound event as per below (Grida is the name of the sample grid)

```
Protected Sub Grida_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Grida.RowDataBound


'check for row in edit mode
    If (e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit) then
' create handles for the row being edited 
   Dim drv As System.Data.DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)

 ' locate the dropdownbox (in my page)

  Dim dllven As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.Cells(3).FindControl("DropDownVendor"), DropDownList)

   ' check what item was selected in this DDL when in editmode

        Dim li As ListItem = dllven.Items.FindByText(drv("Vendor").ToString)

   ' set the selection  upon return

        li.Selected = True



  end if
```

End Sub

works perfectly for me.

Comment: I had added a breakpoint in my GridView1_RowDataBound, but it will not fire when I click the Update button.